# getting error nonce too low while using web3.py with an aws lambda function

Tags: web3.py, aws

I have quite an issue here. I have a web3 py script for integration. It works perfectly on my local machine and also interacting with the smart contract directly from testnet.

The problem is, on AWS lambda (this is where the backend I am integrating with is backend), when I send a transaction first, it work. But when I want to send the second transaction, it gives the error "nonce too low"

Now, it does not give this error in the local machine or interacting from the testnet directly.

I will really appreciate any help on this.

summary is, it is working perfectly on local machine and testnet but not perfectly on AWS lambda

Comment: The nonce needs to be increased for the second transaction, are you saying that you are not increasing it and yet it is working on local testnet? If so are you sure you are not sending them from a fresh state each time?
Short answer should be to just update your transaction dictionary with `nonce += 1` between sending

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to get a refreshed view from your RPC provider (eth_getTransactionCount) for the first transaction being sent by the Lambda script. Keep in mind that nonces are incremental, and nonce numbers shouldn't be reused for a new transaction.

If you are sending several transactions in a row, your RPC provider might not respond you the proper updated nonce, but you can safely increment it yourself (nonce += 1) before sending the subsequent transactions. eg:

```
# initiating transaction session
nonce = w3.get_transaction_count(account, 'pending')

send_transaction(…, nonce)

# wrap this in a loop
nonce = nonce + 1
send_transaction(…, nonce)
```

https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_gettransactioncount

Disclaimer: I work for AWS.